# Minimal sufficient statistic with parameter-dependent support on density function

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics

I'm having trouble finding a minimal sufficient statistic for this particular population. It has the pdf defined as $$f_\theta (x) = 4\theta^4 x^{-5}$$ if $\theta \leq x$, and 0 otherwise. We take $n$ simple random samples $(X_1, ..., X_n) = \vec{X}$.

My work:

I've gathered the density function for $\vec{X}$:
If all the $X_i$ are greater than or equal than $\theta$, then $f_\theta (\vec{x})$ is $$4^n \theta^{4n} \left(\prod^n_{i=1} (x_i)\right)^{-5}$$ otherwise if some $X_i$ is below, the whole function would yield zero.

I immediately see the support depends on theta. If the statistic were $T(\vec{X}) = \prod^n_{i=1} x_i$, I can show this is sufficient if we were to factorize the joint pdf into $h(\vec{x}) = 1$ and $g_\theta (\vec{x}) = 4^n \theta^{4n} \left(\prod^n_{i=1} (x_i)\right)^{-5}$.

This isn't fruitful; later I cannot use the minimal sufficient characterization theorem, because for some $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$, if  $\frac{f_{\theta} (\vec{x})} {f_{\theta} (\vec{y})} = \frac{4^n \theta^{4n} \left(\prod^n_{i=1} (x_i)\right)^{-5}}{4^n \theta^{4n} \left(\prod^n_{i=1} (y_i)\right)^{-5}}$ were independent of $\theta$ (as it already is), it doesn't follow that $T(\vec{x}) = T(\vec{y})$.

I've tried other approaches but cannot find an appropriate statistic yet. How can I find this minimal statistic? This is homework, so I'd appreciate pointers to get to the solution myself.

Comment: Your expression for $f$ is not a pdf: it doesn't integrate to unity.  There must be some restriction on the values of $x$--most likely, $0 \lt \theta\le x \lt \infty.$  *It is crucial to represent this restriction explicitly in all your expressions for $f.$*  That will enable you to solve this problem.

Comment: @whuber You are correct, I've forgotten to type it in. As it stands I couldn't figure it out with that restriction either.

Comment: Step 1: type it in.  If that's not a good enough hint, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245702.

Comment: Consider the relationship between $x$ and $\theta$.  It amounts to "all the elements of $x$ are $> \theta$".   Is there a way to reduce this "all the elements of $x$" statement to one involving a univariate statistic?  (Yes.)  Consider the data $x = 4, 2, 3$.   What is known about $\theta$?