# MLE for a modified German tank problem

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, inference

Suppose I have a distribution $U(0,a)$ where $a$ is unknown and we are interested to estimate it. Someone who has access to $n$ samples $\mu_i$ of this distribution instead decides to create a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu_i$ and standard deviation $\sigma_i$ and draws 1 sample from each of $x_i\sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$ and provides us this $x_i, \sigma_i$. Based on this we would like to estimate distribution of $a$.

Since this problem is quite similar to estimating the distribution of maximum, my approach was to write the CDF of $a$ as the product of individual of CDFs : $$ \phi(a) = \prod_{i=1}^n \phi(a, x_i, \sigma_i)$$, but I know this doesn’t capture the fact that there is a cutoff at $a$. Any ideas on how to improve on this?

Comment: You capture the cutoff by using an indicator function.  This is routine for the simpler version of this problem (where the $n$ samples are directly observed) and continues to apply.

Comment: @whuber Could you please elaborate this more?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20theta%20uniform%20indicator%20is%3aanswer.  A good answer, found among those hits, is https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/245732/919.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. That was useful but it isn't clear to me how that applies to my case where $x_i$ are draws from Gaussian distribution $N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$.

Comment: Your formula for $\phi$ ultimately will involve the (unobserved) values $\mu_i,$ which necessarily lie in the interval $(0,a).$ That's where the indicator function goes.

Comment: But given that I only have 1 draw from each $N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$ will $\mu_i$ ever come in the formula for $\phi$? I thought the only sensible guess for $\mu_i$ given 1 single draw is just the draw $x_i$ itself.

Comment: That would maximize the likelihood *conditional on $a.$* However, it isn't obvious that those choices would maximize the unconditional likelihood.  It's conceivable that shrinking $a$ to be a little less than some of the largest among the $x_i$ would increase the likelihood. In that case, you would have to set the corresponding $\mu_i$ to $a.$ (Similar considerations apply to negative values of $x_i,$ but with no implications for $a.$) Thus, you need to write down the full likelihood accurately and optimize it rigorously (if you're doing MLE).

Comment: (Continued) Indeed, it seems to me that the likelihood is going to be maximized globally by setting all $\mu_i=0$ and letting $a$ approach $0$ from above: the likelihood behaves like $O(a^{-n})$ in that case, which diverges. Adopting a prior distribution for $a$ that has a rapidly vanishing probability near zero ought to rescue you from this.

Comment: @whuber I know that $a$ has a strict lowerbound of $a_0>0$. Would that help? I am kind of stuck on how to even write a likelihood function.

Comment: How are the $\sigma_i$ determined?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to state it more briefly like $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$ with $\mu_i \sim U(0,a)$. How do we estimate $a$ given a sample $X_i$ and given $\sigma_i$? The reason why I suggest this, is because the storyline *"someone who has access..."* Is confusing. Who is this '*someone*' and why do they use $x_i$ as estimation for $a$ if they have also access to $\mu_i$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your specified distributions, the marginal density of $X$ is:

$$\begin{align}
f_X(x) 
&= \int \limits_0^a \text{N}(x |\mu,\sigma^2) \cdot \text{U}(\mu|0,a) \ d \mu \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{a} \int \limits_0^a \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} 
 \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \bigg)^2 \bigg) \ d \mu \\[6pt]
&= -\frac{1}{a} \int \limits_{x/\sigma}^{(x-a)/\sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} 
 \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \bigg)^2 \bigg) \ d ((x-\mu)/\sigma) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{a} \bigg[ \Phi \Big( \frac{x}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x-a}{\sigma} \Big) \bigg]. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

So your log-likelihood function should be:

$$\ell_{\mathbf{x}}(a)
= - n \log(a) + \sum_{i=1}^n \log \bigg[ \Phi \Big( \frac{x_i}{\sigma_i} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x_i-a}{\sigma_i} \Big) \bigg].$$

Note that there is no upper bound on $a$ in this problem because the $x_i$ values all have support over the whole real line irrespective of the value of $a$.  To find the MLE, your score function and information function are:

$$\begin{align}
s_{\mathbf{x}}(a)
\equiv \frac{d \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{da} (a)
&= - \frac{n}{a} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\phi((x_i-a)/\sigma_i)}{\sigma_i H_\mathbf{x}(a)}, \\[12pt]
I_{\mathbf{x}}(a)
\equiv -\frac{d^2 \ell_{\mathbf{x}}}{da^2} (a)
&= - \frac{n}{a^2} - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-a) \cdot \frac{\phi((x_i-a)/\sigma_i)}{\sigma_i^3 H_\mathbf{x}(a)} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\phi((x_i-a)/\sigma_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2 H_\mathbf{x}(a)^2}, \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

where $H_\mathbf{x}(a) \equiv \Phi(x_i/\sigma_i) - \Phi((x_i-a)/\sigma_i)$.  Taking $s_{\mathbf{x}}(\hat{a}) = 0$ and solving numerically for $\hat{a}$ will yield the MLE for $a$.  You should bear in mind that the MLE tends to be a biased estimator for problems involving estimating a maximum-bound parameter, but it is a common form of estimation in general.

Using the laws of iterated expectation and variance, it is simple to show that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \tfrac{1}{2}a$ and $\mathbb{V}(X) = \tfrac{1}{12} a^2 + \sigma^2$.  Consequently, under some relatively weak conditions on the values $\sigma_i$ (ensuring that we don't have a finite subset of values that "dominate" in the limit) we have $2\bar{x}_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Consequently, for large $n$ we ought to have $\hat{a} \approx 2\bar{x}_n$.  (But be careful with this approximation; in some cases we may have $\bar{x}_n \leqslant 0$.)

---

**Implementation in R:** We can implement the numeric solution to the MLE for this problem using the following `R` function.  This function takes in the vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ and returns the MLE $\hat{a}$ and the mean-maximum-log-likelihood $\ell_{\mathbf{x}}(\hat{a})/n$.  (Optimisation is done here using the `nlm` function rather than using a root-finding algorithm on the score function.)  The function also has an option to return the convergence code from the optimisation to check that the numerical maximisation worked properly.

```
MLE.modified.tank <- function(x, sigma = rep(1, length(x)), nlm.code = FALSE) {
  
  #Check inputs
  if (!is.numeric(x))             stop('Error: Input x should be numeric')
  if (!is.numeric(sigma))         stop('Error: Input sigma should be numeric')
  if (length(x) != length(sigma)) stop('Error: Inputs x and sigma should be the same length')
  if (min(sigma) <= 0)            stop('Error: Input sigma should only have positive values')   
  
  #Set objective function using parameterisation p = log(a)
  NEGLOGLIKE <- function(p) {
    n <- length(x)
    LOG1 <- pnorm(x/sigma, log = TRUE)
    LOG2 <- pnorm((x-exp(p))/sigma, log = TRUE)
    LOGDIFF <- LOG1 + VGAM::log1mexp(LOG1 - LOG2)
    n*p - sum(LOGDIFF) }
  
  #Find the MLE
  P0    <- log(max(2*mean(x), 1e-6))
  NLM   <- nlm(f = NEGLOGLIKE, p = P0)
  MLE.a <- exp(NLM$estimate)
  MMAX  <- -NLM$minimum/n
  CODE  <- NLM$code
  
  #Create the output
  OUT <- data.frame(MLE.a = MLE.a, mean.max.loglike = MMAX)
  if (nlm.code) { OUT$nlm.code <- CODE }
  rownames(OUT) <- ''
  
  #Return the output
  OUT }
```

We can implement this function to see if it estimates well.  In the code below we take a set of mock data generated from your model (with known parameter) and we estimate via MLE.  With $n=200$ data points this gives a good estimate of the true parameter.

```
#Set parameters
a <- 20
n <- 200
sigma <- rgamma(n, shape = 6, scale = 0.4)

#Generate some mock data
set.seed(1)
m <- runif(n, min = 0, max = a)
x <- m + sigma*rnorm(n)

#Compute the MLE of a
MLE <- MLE.modified.tank(x, sigma, nlm.code = TRUE)

#Plot the data and MLE
plot(sigma, x, 
     main = '(Blue line shows true parameter - Red line shows MLE)',
     xlab = 'SDs of observed values',
     ylab = 'Observed values')
abline(h = a, lty = 2, col = 'blue')
abline(h = MLE$MLE.a, col = 'red')

#Display the MLE
MLE 

   MLE.a mean.max.loglike nlm.code
 19.7711        -3.178023        1
```

[image]

Comment: For simulated data, I am looking at parameter that maximize the loglikelihood through $dl/da=0$, but I could also plot the likelihood function and look where its maximum lis, and I get a different answer for the two cases. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: It looks like for a single observation $x_i,\sigma_i$, the expectation of $a$ should about $x_i$, but this not what your formulation does. Any ideas?

Comment: @titanium: Actually, we have $\mathbb{E}(X) = a/2$, so for large amounts of data we should have $\hat{a} \approx 2 \bar{x}_n$ (under some weak conditions on the standard deviations).  We can see that this is roughly what we get in the diagram.

Comment: @matttree: Since the log-likelihood is continuous and quasi concave, its maximum point ought to lie at its unique critical point, so these ought to be the same thing.  If you are getting substantially different results then it sounds like either a coding error or an error in the numerical method.